# automatic value for a field in a table (other than primary key)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table "projects" in MySQL (InnoDB). The primary key is id (int auto-increment, starting from 1). In addition, I have in the table invoice_number.

After sometime the client asked the invoice number to be auto generated (starting from 2000).

Unfortunately, I cannot have more than one auto-increment fields in a table. Also, trigger is not working on after insert event because it cannot alter the table being manipulated now.

So how to accomplish my task?

Note: Actually, this is a web based application who is writing into the DB

Comment: For each INSSERT you could do invoice=invoice+1

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a DB mechanism to increment a field, you can do it like this

```
insert into projects (invoice_number)
select case when max(invoice_number) + 1 >= 2000 
            then max(invoice_number) + 1
            else 2000
       end
from projects
```

Select the highest value and increment by 1 manually.

Comment: i agree with you absolutely, but what about invoice starting from 2000

Comment: Actually, this is a web based application who is writing into the DB. So, how can I make use of the suggested code? Is it a trigger?

Comment: @Miracle: No, it is a normal query. You also put the other web data you want to insert in that one query and execute it.

Comment: Is there some other solution on the database layer?